# Bitbucket Pipelines, npm install fails

Tags: npm-install, bitbucket-pipelines

I use a bitbucket pipeline to deploy my develop branch.
Everything work fine so far, but now i have an error in the pipeline :

> - npm install npm ERR! Unexpected token } in JSON at position 803931 while parsing near '...==" npm ERR!         } npm ERR!     } npm ERR!
>   } npm ERR! ' npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm
>   ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-05T14_19_12_739Z-debug.log

Here is my pipeline script :

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
   branches:
      develop: # develop branch 
      - step: 
         deployment: test
         caches:
         - node
         script:
         - npm install
         - npm install -g @angular/cli
         - npm install -g firebase-tools 
         - ng build
```